How to Sum all the agents
I have 50 agents (engines) running through the state chart. When the agent passes into the repair/PeriodMaint/Depot, it gets counted. The variable NRepair for example counts when each agent passes through. So at the run page, I have 50 sets of NRepair data. Sim Run Page showing engine 0 repair count
How do I sum all the agents running through the states at the same reference timing? The counting works fine for all 50 agents.
State Chart
For example: if agent0 and agent 3 both enters into Repair at time 20 hour, the result should be 1 + 1 = 2.
I have tried using the statistics to sum but can't get the expression to work. Engine Main Page
I am trying to model engines running through the various maintenance and to determine the inventory levels.

Welcome to SOF. pls split into 2 questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

noted. have split the questions
